# Search through array in an object using javascript without using a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search

I want to find a better, more elegant solution than using 2 iteration to find a value in an object. I looked at functions to search within an array such as find,indexOf but was wondering I could search through the object without using a for or forEach.

Let say I want to find all swimmers. What I got so far.

```
members = [
  { name: "Sue", hobby: ["Swimming", "Running", "Dancing"] },
  { name: "Sam", hobby: ["Cars", "Travelling"] },
  { name: "John", hobby: ["Reading", "Swimming"] },
  { name: "Rob", hobby: ["Running", "Coding"] },      
];
function findSwimmers(members, hobby) {      
  let swimmers = [];      
  members.forEach(function (e){        
    e.hobby.forEach(function (element){          
      if (element.toLowerCase() === hobby.toLowerCase()) {
        swimmers.push(e);
      }
    });
  });
  return swimmers;
}
```

Comment: *Any* method of searching through an array will use a loop somehow...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `filter` in combination with `some` by passing *callback* functions as argument.

```js
let members = [
  { name: "Sue", hobby: ["Swimming", "Running", "Dancing"] },
  { name: "Sam", hobby: ["Cars", "Travelling"] },
  { name: "John", hobby: ["Reading", "Swimming"] },
  { name: "Rob", hobby: ["Running", "Coding"] },      
];

function findSwimmers(members, hobby) {      
  return members_swimming = members.filter(({hobby}) => hobby.some(item => item == "Swimming"));
                                
}

console.log(findSwimmers(members, "Swimming"));
```

Comment: Suggest incorporating the OP's `toLowerCase` (or similar) rather than hardcoding `"Swimming"`. And possibly even mention [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `sensitivity: "base"` (where available).

Comment: This works great returning the names, but I want to return the object, same as my function would....

Comment: I don't know why you added *map* and assignment. The return statement can be reduced to: `return members.filter(member => member.hobby.some(item => item == hobby));` I think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @PWT, just remove the `map` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.filter()` and `Array.map()` with destructuring:

```js
var members = [
  { name: "Sue", hobby: ["Swimming", "Running", "Dancing"] },
  { name: "Sam", hobby: ["Cars", "Travelling"] },
  { name: "John", hobby: ["Reading", "Swimming"] },
  { name: "Rob", hobby: ["Running", "Coding"] },      
];
var swimmers = members.filter(({hobby}) => hobby.includes('Swimming')).map(({name}) => name);
console.log(swimmers)
```

Comment: The OP's code allows for a case-insensitive match. The above does not. Also, the OP's code returns the member object, not just their name. `map` has no place here.

Answer (score 1):

Any solution is going to involve loops. The only question is whether the loops are in *your* code or a function you call.

In your case, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) seem like the tools to use:

```
function findSwimmers(members, hobby) {
  hobby = hobby.toLowerCase();
  return members.filter(member =>
    member.hobby.some(h => h.toLowerCase() === hobby)
  );
}
```

You might want a different function name. :-)

Live Example:

```js
const members = [
  { name: "Sue", hobby: ["Swimming", "Running", "Dancing"] },
  { name: "Sam", hobby: ["Cars", "Travelling"] },
  { name: "John", hobby: ["Reading", "Swimming"] },
  { name: "Rob", hobby: ["Running", "Coding"] },      
];
function findSwimmers(members, hobby) {
  hobby = hobby.toLowerCase();
  return members.filter(member =>
    member.hobby.some(h => h.toLowerCase() === hobby)
  );
}

console.log(findSwimmers(members, "swimming"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that your original code didn't stop looping when it found a hobby match (and if there were duplicate entries in the hobbies array, would have added the same member more than once — but presumably there aren't meant to be duplicates in that array).

You might also use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), if available, with the `sensitivity: "base"` option rather than comparing lower-case strings.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I understand the native functions will use a loop. I just wanted to use them instead of my own loop. :)

Comment: Unrelated: Today I put up a meta question ( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372795/are-these-good-auto-messages ) regarding good/effective/... "auto" messages when commenting low quality newbie questions. The feedback I received felt pretty much "you are doing the totally wrong thing". Now I am simply wondering how you look at this? Do you have "generic" messages in your quiver, or do you write solely specific comments in such cases?

Comment: @GhostCat - I don't have time now to comment on those specific texts, but I strongly disagree with the people saying "downvote and move on." I do have a quiver of crafted messages, but I ensure that whenever I pick one, I tailor it to the specific situation (I can do that before posting). I don't tell them to take the tour if they have the Informed badge. I don't say "Welcome to Stack Overflow" if they've been a member for two years but this is only their third question. My overriding principle is: The comment must be *useful*, and must be *welcoming*. (This was...not always my rule.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a single line:

```
let swimmers = members.filter(person => person.hobby.includes('Swimming'));
```

Comment: The OP's code allows for a case-insensitive match. The above does not.

Comment: This works great returning the names, but I want to return the object, same as my function would....

Comment: This should return you an array of objects with name and hobby (and anything else you want to add in), where the hobby includes swimming, which I think is what you were looking for? However - as has been pointed out, I haven't accounted for any case mismatch, so my solution is not currently fit for purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First solution: bit of a hack <strike>but hey, no looping</strike>

Second solution: using `Array.findIndex` may reduce the amount of iterations in the inner loop (well, at least gives you some *probability* of less iterations) because ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)):

> ... If such an element is found, findIndex *immediately* returns the index
>   for that iteration ...

```js
const findMembersWithValueForKey = (members, key, value) => 
  members.filter(member => member[key] instanceof Array
    && `#${member[key].join("#")}#`.toLowerCase()
         .indexOf(`#${value.toLowerCase()}#`) > -1
    || false);
    
const findMembersWithValueForKey2 = (members, key, value) => {
    value = value.toLowerCase();
    return members.filter(member => 
      member[key] instanceof Array
      && member[key].findIndex(v => v.toLowerCase() === value) > -1
      || false);
};
    
const members = [
  { name: "Sue", hobby: ["Swimming", "Running", "Dancing"] },
  { name: "Sam", hobby: ["Cars", "Travelling"] },
  { name: "John", hobby: ["Reading", "Swimming"] },
  { name: "Rob", hobby: ["Running", "Coding"] },      
];

console.log(findMembersWithValueForKey(members, "hobby", "swimming"));

console.log(findMembersWithValueForKey2(members, "hobby", "swimming"));
```

Comment: `filter` and `indexOf` are both looping operations. Amusing approach, though. :-)